# Is Brownian Motion increasing?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Given a process
$Y_t = e^{B_t}$

We know that since Brownian motion is continuous for $t \geq 0$.
Since $B_t$ is a completely random motion, it is true that we cannot say whether it is monotone increasing/decreasing over time, no?

So if at some instance, $B_{n} < B_{n+1}$ but $B_{n+1} > B_{n+3}$ then $Y_t$ is not monotone at all, correct?

edit:  The specific question is, is $Y_t$ monotone increasing in $t$ ?

Comment: The probability that there exists some interval $[a,b]$ with $0\leqslant a<b$ such that $B$ (hence $Y$) is monotonous on $[a,b]$ is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say that $B_t$ is monotone with probability 0 (just was we can say $B_t$ is differentiable w.p. 0).

For example, if $B_t$ is now 1, then it will hit $2$ some time later w.p. 1; from here it will some time hit $1$ again w.p. 1.

It follows that $e^{B_t}$ is also monotone with zero probability.

Comment: Is this the conventional way to answer such a question? Why can't It just be said that $B_t$ is not monotone? Is there an inaccuracy/lack of rigor to that statement?

Comment: That would be similar to saying "$B_1$ is not 2."  We know that this is almost always true, but can we say it's true?  For example, if I pick a random number $x \in [0,1]$, then with probability 1 we have $x \neq 1/2$.  Would you say that we can write $x \neq 1/2$?

Comment: Thanks - that makes complete sense!